# can i fill model's fields by tds without javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

is it possible i fill model's fields by content of table's tds. of course without using javascript .
i wanna pass a model to view and get content of tds .
some thing like text box :  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username)

is it possible i have some thing like this for tds?  what can i put in place of tds?

```
                    <tr class="darckTr">
                        <td>code :</td>
                        <td id="tdPobox" colspan="3">12345</td>
                        <td>Email :</td>
                        <td id="tdEmail">example@yahoo.com</td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a display template. Create a .cshtml view, for example "ContactDetails.cshtml":

```
@model ContactDetails

<tr class="darckTr">
    <td>code :</td>
    <td id="tdPobox" colspan="3">@Model.PoBox</td>
    <td>Email :</td>
    <td id="tdEmail">@Model.Email</td>
</tr>
```

If the filename of your partial view matches the type in your model, it will be used automatically. Otherwise, you have a couple of options. Either specify the partial on your model, e.g.:

```
public class MyWrappingClass
{
    [UIHint("_ContactDetails")]
    public ContactDetails Details { get; set; }
}
```

And then do this in your view:

```
@model MyWrappingClass

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Details)
```

Or, just specify the template directly in your view:

```
@model MyWrappingClass

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Details, "_ContactDetails")
```

Brad Wilson wrote a good blog post on templates, including how they are resolved, here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

**Edit**

If you want to persist these values back on POST, you need to have an input element containing the values. In your case, the best way to do this would be to use a hidden field, for example:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Username)
```

Comment: no no , i do'nt want to dispaly . i wanna put td's value in my ViewModel . for example one of my ViewModel property is :  public string email { get; set; } . i wanna put "example@yahoo.com" into it. of cource without java script

Comment: i filled td's by java script . i mean i send "12345" and "example@yahoo.com" by javascript cod to tds . and now how can i get td's values and send to HiddenFor? just with javascript? is there any way?

Comment: i have 3 partial view .there is textbox_phone in partial one . and there is textbox_email in partila two . and there are my tds in partial three. i'll send phone from One to tdPobox in Three By JavaScript .And Send Email from Two To tdEmail in Three .is my work correct?is there security ?  and now , in Partial three i wanna fill my models .how can i bind my tds to model's fileds

Comment: In that case you will have to use JavaScript, yes. As long as the name attribute of the hidden field matches your property, it will be bound. You can find plenty of info on this on google.